# Struts2 action with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, struts2

I've created an action method using `Struts2` which returns `stream` to download a file. I am not saving the file anywhere. While testing this action using `JUnit` I get `FileNotFound` which is valid because the file is not saved anywhere because when I invoke the action it comes as a `stream`. So, how can I test this situation then?

Action Method.

```
private static final String DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE = "DocuSignEnvelopeReport.csv";

public String viewReport() throws Exception {
    boolean returnReport;
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE);

    try {
        returnReport = validateRequest();
        if (returnReport) {

        intgList = this.generateViewIntegrationReportData(getESignUIConfig());
        this.createCSVFile(intgList, DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE);

        } else {
            failureResponse(msgs, 400);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        msgs.add(new Message(ESignatureIntegrationMessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR, 
                    UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_CODE_500, UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_TEXT_SERVICE_ERROR));
        failureResponse(msgs, 500);
        return null;
    }

    return UiIntegrationKeyConstants.REPORT_REPSONSE;
}
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="*Integration" method="{1}" class="com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.webapp.action.ESignatureIntegrationAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">integrationView</result>  
        <result name="reportResponse" type="stream"> 
            <param name="contentType">application/text/csv</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>  
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="DocuSignEnvelopeReport.csv"</param> 
            <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
        </result>  
</action>
```

JUnit so far

```
@Test
public void testViewReport() throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
    actionMap.put( "application", "ESignatureIntegrationAction" );
    ActionContext context = new ActionContext( actionMap );
    ActionContext.setContext(context);

    action = new ESignatureIntegrationAction();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream( new File( "DocuSignEnvelopeReport.csv" ) );
    action.setInputStream( inputStream );

    String actionReturn = action.viewReport();

    assertNotNull( actionReturn );

}
```

When it gets to `inputStream = new FileInputStream(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE);` it throws `FileNotFound`.

Comment: The issue is clear: the file isn't found. It needs to be located at an absolute location (or a resource if it's compiled into the code).

Comment: You are right and this is what I asked how to test this situation without creating a file in a file system. I found PowerMock has a method whennew which allows to mock situations like this.